# Do any studies on 'Long COVID' compare to a control group?

Tags: covid-19, statistics

[This](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/32644129/) study, which is citied in a [Harvard Health](https://www.health.harvard.edu/blog/the-tragedy-of-the-post-covid-long-haulers-202010152479) article on Long COVID, shows that ~55% of people suffered fatigue 6 weeks after having COVID-19:

[image]

But it doesn't compare against the prevalence of 'fatigue' in a control group. (that is, the baseline prevalence of 'fatigue' in the population, according to the study's definition, could be 2%, it could be 50% - or anything else - but we just don't know simply because measurements weren't taken from a control group).

Are there any studies that compare the possible long term symptoms of COVID-19 against a control group?

Comment: I know of one such international study, so yes. It is ongoing and not yet published, though.

Comment: @Aolon please share it when it’s published

Comment: Sure, no problem.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be exactly the controls you want, but here is [news](https://www.voanews.com/covid-19-pandemic/vaccines-reduce-risk-long-covid-symptoms-study-finds) about one study that compared "long Covid" symptoms in vaccinated (breakthrough infection) vs unvaccinated:

> In a study published Wednesday in the Lancet Infectious Diseases journal, scientists at King’s College London surveyed more than one million fully vaccinated volunteers who used a mobile app to log their symptoms, tests and vaccination status, and compared them to a control group of unvaccinated volunteers.
>
> The study says that only a fraction of the vaccinated volunteers reported so-called “breakthrough infections,” and that those who did were 73% less likely to be hospitalized. It also said **the chances the vaccinated respondents would continue to suffer from so-called “long COVID” symptoms is reduced by nearly half**.

Slightly more commentary in the [press release](https://www.kcl.ac.uk/news/double-vaccination-halves-risk-of-long-covid):

> Professor Tim Spector from King’s College London and Lead investigator of ZOE COVID Study comments: “Vaccinations are massively reducing the chances of people getting Long COVID in two ways. Firstly, by reducing the risk of any symptoms by 8 to 10 fold and then by halving the chances of any infection turning into Long COVID, if it does happen.”

In the methods section of the [actual paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/S1473-3099(21)00460-6) the (vaccinated) controls are detailed as follows:

> For the risk factor analysis, cases had received a first or second dose of a COVID-19 vaccine between Dec 8, 2020, and July 4, 2021; had either a positive COVID-19 test at least 14 days after their first vaccination (but before their second; cases 1) or a positive test at least 7 days after their second vaccination (cases 2); and had no positive test before vaccination. Two control groups were selected (who also had not tested positive for SARS-CoV-2 before vaccination): users reporting a negative test at least 14 days after their first vaccination but before their second (controls 1) and users reporting a negative test at least 7 days after their second vaccination (controls 2). Controls 1 and controls 2 were matched (1:1) with cases 1 and cases 2, respectively, by the date of the post-vaccination test, health-care worker status, and sex. In the disease profile analysis, we sub-selected participants from cases 1 and cases 2 who had used the app for at least 14 consecutive days after testing positive for SARS-CoV-2 (cases 3 and cases 4, respectively). Controls 3 and controls 4 were unvaccinated participants reporting a positive SARS-CoV-2 test who had used the app for at least 14 consecutive days after the test, and were matched (1:1) with cases 3 and 4, respectively, by the date of the positive test, health-care worker status, sex, body-mass index (BMI), and age. We used univariate logistic regression models (adjusted for age, BMI, and sex) to analyse the associations between risk factors and post-vaccination infection, and the associations of individual symptoms, overall disease duration, and disease severity with vaccination status.